# How to input large data from files in C

Tags: c

This is the general way in which i input data into an array

```
         for(i=1to size)
        {
            scanf(%d",&a[i]);

      }
```

what if there large number of inputs? like a file containing a 100000 numbers
and size is given from the terminal

Comment: You need dynamically allocated arrays. Use `malloc`, don't use variable-length arrays.

Comment: The thing is i dont know how to use malloc.can this code be modified to take input data from txt file which i have containing 1 lakh integers? and Does finding just the split inversions in merge sort work? i mean to find the total number of inversions

Comment: @saratb Try googling for malloc. You need to learn how to use the reference manuals, this is basic stuff. I know we all need to start somewhere, but being able to read and understand the manuals is an important skill that you need to learn

Answer (score 2):

```
int a[size];
```

Is what's wrong with your code.
You're allocating memory for an array by using a variable, which allocates it on your stack. If you allocate more than the stack can allow, what you achieve is a ... stack overflow!

You need to allocate the memory on heap by using malloc(). The way you do this is:

```
int * a;
a = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
```

If you want to read more about malloc, reasons for using it and how to use it, google is your friend.

Comment: Oh thanks i will do that ...what about input from file? how to do that i mean i cant input those many integers from command prompt

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. Either your C program can open the file and start reading from it or you can pass the data to your program (if you're using linux, just do ./a.out < data.txt)

Comment: FILE *fp;
         fp=fopen("Input.txt","r");
         for(i=1;i<=size;i++)
          {
             fscanf(fp,"%d\n",&a[i]);
         }               its working perfectly now using malloc and                   this